# Integrate Normal Distribution Between 2 Values

Tags: r, distribution

I want to calculate the integral of the Normal Distribution at exactly some point - I know that to do this, this is the equivalent of integrating the Normal Distribution at that point and at some point slightly after that point : then, you can subtract both of these values and get an approximate answer.

I tried doing this in R:

```
a = pnorm(1.96, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE)
b = pnorm(1.961, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE)

final_answer = b - a

 #5.83837e-05
```

- Is it possible to do this in one step instead of manually subtracting "a" and "b"?

Thank you!

Comment: The integral of the normal distribution - of any function, in fact - at “*exactly* some point” - is precisely zero. It’s not clear why you need an approximate answer when the exact answer is known by definition.

Comment: Sounds like you're maybe looking for `dnorm` instead of `pnorm`?

Answer (score 3):

We need to be clear about what you are asking here. If you are looking for the integral of  a normal distribution at a specific point, then you can use `pnorm`, which is the anti-derivative of `dnorm`.

We can see this by reversing the process and looking at the derivative of `pnorm` to ensure it matches `dnorm`:

```r
# Numerical approximation to derivative of pnorm:
delta <- 10^-6

(pnorm(0.75 + delta) - pnorm(0.75)) / delta
#> [1] 0.3011373
```

Note that this is a very close approximation of `dnorm`

```r
dnorm(0.75)
#> [1] 0.3011374
```

So the anti-derivative of a normal distribution density at point x is given by:

```r
pnorm(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like "prnorm" is naturally suited for this task?

Comment: Your description of your problem was a little unclear, but if I have understood what you are looking for, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
> diff(pnorm(c(1.96, 1.961), mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE))
[1] 5.83837e-05
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is a good alternative!